# How to Highlight Text in Text Box using blend 4

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend-4

I'm studying blend my self and I'm stuck with a silly problem and I don't know how to solve this I'm creating a log in page in blend and I want to do two things on the text box first **I want to change the text color in the textbox**  and second I want to create the text box exactly like the text box used in the twitter log in (means **I want to highlight the "username or email" in my tetx box**) and I'm completely stuck with this problem how to solve this... pardon me for this silly question

Comment: Do you want to highlight the entire text in the text box or just some part of it?

Comment: You can use `Foreground` for that. If you want to watermark your textbox, you can either do it yourself or find some control that supports it.